# Arquivo de conexão PDO. Como usar?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho um arquivo de conexão PDO. Para incluir esta conexão nos outros arquivos do sistema afim de fazer as requisições no banco de dados, vou usar isso????

```
<?php require('conexao.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Tá... agora, qual sua dúvida?

Comment: respondendo: sim..... more any information?

Comment: Se você que sabe o conteúdo do arquivo está em dúvida, imagine nós.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, sua dúvida ficou 'meio' vaga pra mim, quer dizer, meio é apenas pra não dizer completamente, mas enfim...

O arquivo `PDO` que voce deve estar se referindo funciona como uma `classe`, costuma-se criar um arquivo separado e fazer apenas um `require_once` por praticidade, mas claro, se em toda interação com o banco, voce quiser abrir uma `conexão` com o banco manualmente, é so vc colocar no seu código sem fazer referencias

Aqui na empresa usamos 3 `classes` para conexão com um banco...

`pdo.php` <-- onde realizamos a conexão, digamos física;

`cmd_sql.php` <-- onde criamos classes para nos auxilias a montar o `SQL`;

`dadosconectabanco.php` <-- onde colocamos os dados necessarios no `pdo.php` para realizar a conexão ao banco

Nesse último vale ressaltar que devemos criar um pra cada sistema, isso porque ele deve conter informações mais especificas sobre o banco que voce vai se conectar, seja `SQL`, `oracle` ou anyother.. informações tipo: `Porta`, `IP`, `Schema`, <--[1] `Tabela`, `Login`, `senha`, etc, etc

[1] - Esses voce pode colocar direto no `PDO`, muitas vezes esses dados são meio padrões